# Probable circular dependency, but query still runs

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench, database-theory

I built this ER diagram in MySQL Workbench and it will run and generate the database.  My concern is that the relationship between the `employees`, `departments`, `positions`, and `employment_statuses` is a circular relationship.

Because I know people will ask, this is something I was working on in a class.  I'm not asking for help with homework; this is something we were working on in class and I took a different route than the professor.  I'm asking for clarification about database modelling theory.

[image]

Comment: Are `employment_statuses` relevant to `Positions`?  Shouldn't `Positions` have its own `Position_statuses` table?

Comment: Every time the employee would be promoted or their salary changed or or if they resign a new row would be created in `employment_statuses` for each change to keep a historical record.

Comment: Sure, but that only necessitates the `employees` -> `employment_statuses` relation.  `Positions` don't have `employment_statuses`, do they?

Comment: Position changes would be tracked in `employment_statuses` as well.  If someone were to be a Database Engineer Level 1 and they were promoted to a Database Engineer Level 2 it would generate a new record.

Comment: I don't see a circular path here. I see 2 paths from `employees` to `employment_statuses`

Comment: Ahh, so then you don't actually need the `employees` -> `departments` relationship, unless you want the most performance out of a query that lists each employee by department.  In short, your design is fine, if it is a little "interesting".

Comment: The `employees` -> `departments` relationship keeps track of the department manager, as each department has exactly one manager.

As a side note, I appreciate the use of "interesting", I was wondering when that would pop up.

Comment: I find it interesting that you identified as suspect the tables you did, but not the relationships between `employees`, `employees_projects` and `projects` -- it's the same situation with one less table. (There's nothing wrong with the design, I'm just giving you food for thought.)

Comment: I pointed out `employees`, `positions`, `departments`, and `employment_statuses` because that's the relationship I was focusing on.  `employees`, `employees_projects` and `projects` got lost in the shuffle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your model. *Au contraire* - it's pretty advanced!

`employment_statuses` provide data in a time-lined, **historical**, fashion, whilst `departments` identifies the **actual** manager.

These entities are very different both in purpose and use (queries on `employment_statuses` will serve different scenarios than those on `manager`).

I have to congratulate you, as I repeatedly work with peers that just can’t abstract this kind of scenario (the majority just see the *now*, or, at maximum, a single *then* - not the natural sequence of *thens* leading to the *as today*).

A remark: you should move `high/low_salary` from `positions` to another time-lined entity.

Comment: One more thing. My models **always** consider `end_date = 2100/jan/01` as _from now on_. This provide simpler, more straightforward, queries: `... WHERE TODAY BETWEEN start_date AND end_date`. The _natural_ way of setting `end_date = NULL` leads to `... WHERE start_date <= TODAY AND (end_date >= TODAY OR end_date IS NULL)`. Of course, for input controls at the user interfaces, the code has to interpret `2100/jan/01` as `blank`, and vice-versa.

Comment: I'll mark this as correct after I have a discussion with my professor about the model again.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You're welcome. Accueil to the wonderful world of modeling and administering databases.